# Using Linux terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I'm watching a course InfiniteSkills-Learning TCP/IP by Ric Messier and he is using Mac OS X terminal and in the lesson he connect to a Linux terminal to show netstat utility in more detail and I see some differences between both netstat utilities.
How can connect from Mac OS X Mountain Lion to a Linux terminal like this course? Need to install Linux on Parallels Desktop and then connect to Linux terminal in someway?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may open OSX terminal by navigating to `Application > utilities > Terminal.App`.
Once there, you may have different ways to connect to a Linux server which are dependant on where is located and which communication protocol you want to use.

If your Linux server is enabled to be controlled by SSH, you can just type `SSH address` and log in remotely.

Please note that [netstat](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html) is available also in the Max OSX terminal.

Comment: `SSH address` will only work if the filesystem is case-insensitve...

Comment: Thanks Saturnix for your reply. My question is focus how to use Linux terminal locally under Mac OS X terminal and for using netstat's linux version instead of Mac os x because netstat for mac brings less information. Ric Messier seems to use Linux's netstat in the lesson under Mac OS X terminal and use it locally. How can get that Messier's results?

Comment: @user2746680 Like Saturnix said, SSH is the way to go. For the sake of completeness one might want to mention Telnet as well, but for the love of god, don't use it (for pretty much the same reason you don't go out on the street and shout the story of your sexlife at everyone who passes by)

Comment: it really depends on how/where is Linux installed and which communication protocols are enabled.